# AIrflow 2.5.0 webserver not updating "code" tab

Tags: airflow-webserver

Airflow 2.5.0 is syncing the new code correct and scheduler is executing the updated code , even when some change is made , but the webserver code isn't updating at all .
I already setup almost all that I find out here https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.5.0/configurations-ref.html related with webserver update , but it's not updating it yet . Someone knows what I need to do to have the code updated in webserver as well when some change is made ?

This is the updated code that it's running :

```
import logging
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
import redshift_connector
import next.plugins.facebook_marketing
import os
from next.io.utils.helpers import generate_dag_config

dag_config = generate_dag_config()
dag_config['dag_id'] = 'TESTING_DAG'
dag_config['tags'] = ['maintenance']
dag_config['default_args']['owner'] = 'engineering'
dag_config['default_args']['developer'] = 'rafael paiva'
dag_config['schedule_interval'] = None


def main():    
    print("TESTING444")

with DAG(**dag_config) as dag:
    task = PythonOperator(task_id=f'TESTING', python_callable=main)
```

[image]